# How to convert a WSQ fingerprint in base 64 to a image format in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, base64, fingerprint

I have a WSQ fingerprint in base 64 and I need to convert it in a image (any format) to show on my web page. Is that possible?

Answer (score -2):

Yes. Insert the base64 value in the src attribute in the img element

Comment: No, browsers do not understand WSQ format.